# understanding the properties of a measure space

Tags: measure-theory

A measure space is a triple $(X,\sum , \mu)$
where

(i) X is a set.

(ii) $\sum$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of X.

(iii)$\mu : \sum \to [0,\infty]$ is a function such that

(a) $\mu \phi =0$

(b) if $<E_n>_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a disjoint sequence in $\sum$, then 
$\mu(\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n)=\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu E_n$

Intuitively, how can $\mu : \sum \to [0,\infty]$ be interpreted? Is it just saying that the function $\mu$ assigns a length between 0 and $\infty$ to a collection of subsets of X?

How can (iii) (b) be interpreted intuitively?  What is it saying and why is it required? How can it be deduced?

Comment: The concept of measure is a generalization of that of area, like the concept of metric generalizing that of distance. Condition (iii)(b) is to assume away cases not of interest (or pathological cases) in order to preserve our intuition of the thing that the total length of two disjoint intervals of the real line should be the sum of the lengths of the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

For once the name has been appropriately chosen. It's a *measure* so it can represent the length of line segments, the area of planar figures, the volume of solids, etc.

Condition (iii)(b) is called countable additivity. It corresponds to the requirement that we should be able to compute the length of an infinite chain of intervals by either subtracting the end points of the chain or by computing the sum of a series and still obtain the same result.

It cannot be deduced from anything, it's a hypothesis.

There is a parallel theory where countable additivity is replaced with the weaker condition of finite additivity (you can guess how to formulate that condition).

The main reason why people prefer the stronger hypothesis is integration theory.

Integrals have better properties in a countably additive theory than in a finitely additive theory.

Comment: "It corresponds to the requirement that we should be able to compute the length of an infinite chain of intervals by either subtracting the end points of the chain or by computing the sum of a series and still obtain the same result."       How can you tell this by looking at the definition?

Comment: I am not saying that it is equivalent, I only meant to give an example. Let $\mu$ be a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the real numbers, and let $x_1<x_2<x_3<\ldots$ be an increasing sequence with limit $x$ ( could be infinity). We want the sum of the measures of the individual intervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ to be equal to $\mu([x-x_1]).$ The sets $E_n$ are the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the measure "measures" a size of given set. $\Sigma$, which may be called "$\sigma$-algebra", means the collection of sets which are measurable.

(iii) (b) is called $\sigma$-additivity. You can adapt the finite-additivity of $\mu$, which states that $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. $\sigma$-additivity just extend the finite-additivity to infinite sums, but it is quite useful when handling the limit occurring in measure theory.